# How to bencode non-ascii strings and non-integer numbers?

Tags: encoding, bencoding

According to the [bencoding specification](https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Bencoding):

> Bencoded strings are encoded as follows: `<string length encoded in base ten ASCII>:<string data>`, or `key:value`
>   Note that there is no constant beginning delimiter, and no ending delimiter.
>
> **Example**: 4:spam represents the string "spam" 
>   **Example**: 0: represents the empty string ""
>
> Integers are encoded as follows: **i**`<integer encoded in base ten ASCII>`**e**
>   The initial **i** and trailing **e** are beginning and ending delimiters. You can have negative numbers such as **i**-3**e**. Only the significant digits should be used, one cannot pad the Integer with zeroes. such as **i**04**e**. However, **i**0**e** is valid.
>
> Example: **i**3**e** represents the integer "3"

---

*My questions*:

**Question 1**: How should I bencode a string with non-ascii characters? For example: `mûrier` or `die höhe Zeit` Shall I convert a such string to the sequence of bytes, using `UTF-8` encoding, or another one? And how does it apply to the specification?

**Question 2**: How to bencode a non-integer number, for example `1.0002910` or `-0.0049172`?

Comment: To downvoter(s), please leave a comment to let me know what is wrong with my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From the spec, "All character string values are UTF-8 encoded."
2. Not covered by the spec; Apparently not needed.